# Como trocar a cor de um texto de acordo com o estado do objeto?

Tags: react, react-native

Como eu poderia trocar a cor do texto de acordo com o estado do objeto, por exemplo:

```js
const pagamento = [
    {
      id: '1',
      title: '30/05/2020',
      state: true
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      title: '30/06/2040',
      state: false
    },

]
```

Estou usando uma `<FlatList>`. Quero ler esse array e quando for `true` colocar cor verde, quando for `false` colocar vermelho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode adicionar ao estilo do texto do item

```
<FlatList
data={pagamento}
keyExtractor={item => item.id}
renderItem={({item})=> <Text style={{color: item.state ? "green" : "red" }}> {item.title}</Text>}/>
```

assim você terá uma lista com texto com cores dinâmicas de acordo com o state

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Acho que você está precisando de algo assim:

[image: flatlist background color]

O JSON usado foi

```
[
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "30/05/2020",
    state: true
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "30/06/2040",
    state: false
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    title: "30/06/2040",
    state: null
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    title: "30/06/2040",
    state: undefined
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    title: "30/06/2040",
    state: false
  },
  {
    id: "6",
    title: "30/05/2020",
    state: true
  },
  {
    id: "7",
    title: "30/05/2020",
    state: true
  }
]
```

Você pode criar uma screen com o código abaixo para obter o resultado, lembre-se, de me avisar se eu lhe ajudei.

```
// libraries/frameworks
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const pagamento = [
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "30/05/2020",
    state: true
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "30/06/2040",
    state: false
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    title: "30/06/2040",
    state: null
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    title: "30/06/2040",
    state: undefined
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    title: "30/06/2040",
    state: false
  },
  {
    id: "6",
    title: "30/05/2020",
    state: true
  },
  {
    id: "7",
    title: "30/05/2020",
    state: true
  }
];

const backgroundColorItem = ({ state, index }) => {
  const style = index === 0 ? { marginTop: 0 } : {};

  switch (state) {
    case true:
      return { ...style, backgroundColor: "green" };
    case false:
      return { ...style, backgroundColor: "red" };
    default:
      return style;
  }
};

const Item = ({ index, state, title }) => (
  <View style={[styles.item, backgroundColorItem({ state, index })]}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => <Item title={item.title} index={index} state={item.state} />;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList data={pagamento} renderItem={renderItem} keyExtractor={item => item.id} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 20
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: "#ccc",
    padding: 20,
    marginTop: 5
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 12
  }
});
```

Comment: ajudou sim, muito obrigado.